# How to Position a CSS Element on the page? Without position properties?

Tags: html, css

I made 4 progress bars out of CSS, and inserted them into my container, however I cant get them to move from the left without it messing up, I want them to be so that when people resize the browser window it also moves with it.

IMAGE 1: This is what happens when I add a "Position: ___" property:

[image: snapshot]

Without the position property, it seems to stay and move correctly, which is good except I now want to move the bars around as I desire on the page.

HTML

```
<div class="meter">
  <span style="width: 90%"></span>
</div>
<div class="meter">
  <span style="width: 70%"></span>
</div>
<div class="meter">
  <span style="width: 50%"></span>
</div>
<div class="meter">
  <span style="width: 90%"></span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.meter { 
  height: 15px;  /* Can be anything */
        margin-bottom: 10px;
  top: 80px;
    left: 600px;
    background: #555;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
        width: 210px;
    padding: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow   : inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    box-shadow        : inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
.meter > span {
  display: block;
    height: 100%;
       -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
           -moz-border-radius-topright: 8px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 8px;
               border-top-right-radius: 8px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
        -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
     -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
            -moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px;
         -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 20px;
                border-top-left-radius: 20px;
             border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    background-color: rgb(43,194,83);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
      linear,
      left bottom,
      left top,
      color-stop(0, rgb(43,194,83)),
      color-stop(1, rgb(84,240,84))
     );
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(
      center bottom,
      rgb(43,194,83) 67%,
      rgb(84,240,84) 69%
     );
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
      center bottom,
      rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
      rgb(84,240,84) 69%
     );
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(
      center bottom,
      rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
      rgb(84,240,84) 69%
     );
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(
      center bottom,
      rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
      rgb(84,240,84) 69%
     );
    -webkit-box-shadow: 
      inset 0 2px 9px  rgba(255,255,255,0.3),
      inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 
      inset 0 2px 9px  rgba(255,255,255,0.3),
      inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[DEMO](http://cssdesk.com/8bj6U)

(If the answer is some type of float, noticed what happens to the progress bars when you add a "float: right;" in the CSS Desk link I provided above, try adding a float to the code. The bars become vertical aligned)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add these CSS rules to the `.meter` class:

```
float: right;
clear: right;
```

Here's the [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8s6BF/).

Leo!

**EDIT**: If you want to move an element "under your control" (not occurred to me a better definition) and inside the container (I mean, not with respect to the browser's window) just add these CSS rules:

**To the parent element:**

```
position: relative;
```

**To the child element:**

```
position: absolute;
top: value;
right: value;
left: value;
bottom: value;
```

Where `top`, `right`, `left` and `bottom` properties are to move the element *"under your control"*.

I hope that you understand me.

---

This is the difference between add the `position: absolute` to the child without add the `position: relative` to parent, and do it:

**Markup**:

```
<div>
  <img src="images/img.png" />
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet....</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
div img {
  position: absolute;
  top:  50px; 
  left: 50px;
}
```

[image]

As you can see the reference to make the position is the browser's window.

BUT, if you add the `position: relative;` to the parent...

```
div {
  border: 2px solid #CCC;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em 0 1em 4em;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

div img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px; 
  left: 50px;
}
```

[image]

The reference is the parent element.

---

The pictures were obtain from http://www.librosweb.com (a great site to learn about web technologies - in spanish).

Comment: Okay, but It just did the same issue except now its stuck on the right side instead of the left.... I want to be able to position them around together as one. I tried adding "left: __px;" or "top__px;" but nothing happened? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand what you want... Can you be more specific? What do you mean with "around"? To the center? Or some position in the screen?

Comment: Oh sure. I just mean to be able to custom move them a little more to the center, maybe farther downwards in the page, or 90 pixels from the right, or maybe 50 pixels from the right, etc... That type of thing, so its not just fixed/stuck to the right edge of the page. Thanks

Comment: I've updated the post. Don't forget to create a "container" element for wrap the `.meter` elements with their respective childs. If you don't want to modify the markup, just add the `position: relative;` to the body (or the preceded element).

Comment: Yikes! okay, well this is as far as I got: http://cssdesk.com/8bj6U Still not really functional, just allows up and down. Sorry, I dont what any of that really means, but that's my problem!

Comment: Yeah, I understand the relative versus absolute, that makes sense. But as far as the whole child, parent, and wrap thing....way out my skills. Sorry, Im very starter at this. I was hoping it wouldnt be to complex for me to solve but idk. But thanks for those images and links.

Comment: Yep, but in the previous example you don't "respect the pattern" (me and my terminologies =) ): I think that this is what you want: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tQ9st/)

Comment: HEY! So that's it, that's the whole final code? Interesting, Now that I see it written out complete, it makes a bit more sense. Originally when you mentioned "dont forget the container"... i was thinking youre talking about the main website's container that already exists. Derr. But yeah it makes sense looking at it. Awesome! Thanks dude!